# Typescript: (intermediate value).(...) is not a function when call a method of parent class from derived class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, super

This my parent class, it has `trigger` method which is `public` method:

```
class BaseEffect {
    //properties and contructor...
    //other methods...

    public trigger = (): void => void (this.target.hitPoint -= this.amount);
}
```

And a `TurnBasedEffect` extends `BaseEffect` class:

```
class TurnBasedEffect extends BaseEffect {
    //properties and contructor...
    //other methods...

    public trigger = (): void => {
        super.trigger();
        this.remainingTurns--;
    };
}
```

This class also has `trigger` method, inside this method, a `trigger` method of the parent class is called.

The problem is when a `trigger` method of the derived class is called, typescript throws this error:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).trigger is not a function
```

And point to this line of the `trigger` method of the `TurnBasedEffect` class:

```
//...
super.trigger();
//...
```

What's wrong with my classes and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a field that’s initialized to an arrow function. The initialization is done by the constructor:

```js
class Foo {
    bar = () => {};
}

console.log(new Foo().bar);
console.log(new Foo().hasOwnProperty('bar'));
console.log(Foo.prototype.bar);
```

The field doesn’t end up in the prototype chain, so it isn’t inherited, and you can’t call it through `super`.

I suggest writing normal methods:

```
class BaseEffect {
    //properties and contructor...
    //other methods...

    public trigger() {
        this.target.hitPoint -= this.amount;
    }
}

class TurnBasedEffect extends BaseEffect {
    //properties and contructor...
    //other methods...

    public trigger() {
        super.trigger();
        this.remainingTurns--;
    }
}
```

Comment: But what when we can't change base class, is there any convenient way for this? I have concrete example of overriding sortingDataAccessor method of MatTableDataSource in @angular/material.  I want to override it, do something and then call the super call.

Comment: @ceruleus: In the constructor, you can capture its original value before overwriting it.